# How to combine mysql select statements in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to run select statements, and then store the results. However I don't want to union them all together.

I have this:

```
function downloaddata() {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM players", function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            downloadwalls(rows);
        }
    });
}
function downloadwalls(playerdata) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM walls", function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            downloadprojectiles(playerdata, rows);
        }
    });
}
function downloadprojectiles(playerdata, walldata) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM projectiles", function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            gamedata = {
                data : playerdata,
                walls : walldata,
                projectiles : rows
            };
            downloaddata();
        }
    });
}
```

And I basically chain the function to call the next one when its done, then repeat this forever.

Is there a way I can just combine them all something like

```
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM walls; SELECT * FROM ...; SELECT * FROM ...", function(err, rows, fields) {
        // here 'rows' would be an array of arrays of rows...
    });
```

NOTE that, each of tables has different columns so I can't union them.

Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice new version of a Forkbomb, just it fills the stack linear instead of exponentiell. Or has node.js Tail Recursion Detection?

Technical solution: Definitely remove the chaining calls from the functions. Remove the functions too, they don't help since you can not call them right now from outside.

```
function load_data{
    while(true){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM players", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            } else {
                gamedata['data'] = rows;
            }
        });
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM walls", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            } else {
                gamedata['walls'] = rows;
            }
        });
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM projectiles", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            } else {
                gamedata['projectiles'] = rows
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**But don't expect the servers to be happy about that!**

Definitely think about a Redis-Message-Subscribe scheme for this "what's new" question, since you would block a whole CPU on the node.js and on the MySQL-Server for this. Store your data in the database and send a message. I think node.js even brings some nice messaging infos to synchronize data between Servers.

If you have to do it through MySQL, then create a "diff" table and store each Insert, Delete, Update of players, walls, projectiles in that "diff" table through triggers. When 5 users are inactive and 1 is active, you only need to read this single updating player. So the diff table would work as a Message table and you would delete seen messages.